# ECS Docker container won't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a Docker container with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.1

RUN rm -fR /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | \
  debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | \
  debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /app

# Environment Variables
ENV PORT 8080

# start the SSH daemon service
RUN service ssh start

# create a non-root user & a home directory for them
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash tunnel-user
# set their password
RUN echo 'tunnel-user:93wcBjsp' | chpasswd

# Copy the SSH key to authorized_keys
COPY tunnel.pub /app/
RUN mkdir -p /home/tunnel-user/.ssh
RUN cat tunnel.pub >> /home/tunnel-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R tunnel-user:tunnel-user /home/tunnel-user/.ssh
RUN chmod 0700 /home/tunnel-user/.ssh
RUN chmod 0600 /home/tunnel-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

# allow the tunnel-user to SSH into this machine
RUN echo 'AllowUsers tunnel-user' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 22

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

My ECS task has [this](https://pastebin.com/kj1ZNeTy) definition.  I'm using a role which has AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role.

When I try to start it as a task in my ECS cluster I get this error:

```
CannotStartContainerError: API error (500): driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ecs-ssh-4-ssh-8cc68dbfaa8edbdc0500 (387e024a87752293f51e5b62de9e2b26102d735e8da500c8e7fa5e1b4b4f0983): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you check if your ECS agent connection status is "True" or "False"?

Comment: I don't know what can cause this, but I rebooted the ec2 instance and it helped. #unplug_and_plug_back_in_again